# Scaling the audio output of specific device

Tags: keyboard, audio

I got an Anker USB-C dock for my Macbook that has an incredibly hot headphone output. Basically its useful range is only the first two notches of volume control. Even when using shift-option-volumekey to get 0.25-notch adjustment, it's too coarse to get just the right volume.

Is there any way to remap the volume adjustment keys to a smaller range for a specific device? I want to preserve full volume when using the built-in speakers for output. So that the Mac's event handler for volume key events behaves something like:

```
def VolumeKeyHandler(currentDevice, value):
    if currentDevice == "AnkerDock":
        system.setVolume(0.15 * value)
    else:
        system.setVolume(value)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could get an impedance adapter for the headset. Ideally you need to know what impedance the op amp of the Anker is designed to feed & what your headphones actually are, then get a make-up so the total impedance is the same. These are not very common, but they are available, in TRS & TRRS. They seem to be in the order of $£€ 10. [example](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/123907294010?hash=item1cd973433a:g:ObkAAOSw0cVdWKQT)

Comment: Some background: 'Pro' headphones have traditionally always been high impedance [Hi-Z], consumer low impedance[Lo-Z]. Hi-Z needs a better amplifier to drive them, so have long been avoided in consumer gear for cost/miniaturisation reasons. Recent drives to provide professionals with better op amps has led Apple to now include these in current laptop specs. These Macs are smart-switching, maybe the Anker isn't switchable or needs to be 'told' somewhere - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT212856

Comment: I had the parts, so I ended up making an adapter myself with resistors in series. If other readers do this, make sure to account for the resistor's power rating.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) You could put that in an answer & mark it accepted, which will make it easier for future searchers to find.